# Jewish sources on Spanish Inquisition

Tags: history, jewish-books

During and after the Holocaust, there were many situations, which although horrible, required שאלות ותשובות from many of the rabbis at the time on certain questions in הלכה pertaining to the Holocaust. Were there any ספרים written at the time of the Spanish Inquisition pertaining to halachic questions or about them from that time period?

Comment: הקדמת אברבנאל, הקדמת חסיד יעבץ

Comment: The Mahari has a teshuva about children from marranos